# Merge an image at the end of mp4 file using ffmpeg?

Tags: java, ffmpeg, jpeg, mp4

How can I merge a jpg image at the end of an mp4 video file using ffmpeg and Java?

Comment: To clarify, you want to append an image file at the end of the video, and display it for a few seconds before playback stops, right ?

Comment: yes this is what I want. Is it possible with ffmpeg?